# PyQT5 QComboBox - get value of combobox

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5, signals-slots, qcombobox

I am still very new to Qt but I am developing a type of calculator and want to use a combobox to select a coefficient. I have had success creating a combobox with a liststore in pyGT but it appears pyQT is quite different.

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the data models and list models. Essentially I want to have a name show up in the combobox and have the value of that name get passed to the calculator equation. Everything I have seen so far has been just for single entries and not 'associated' entries.

Can anyone explain or point me to a tutorial to walk me through what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [addItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem) to add a name (text) with an associated value (data):

```
    self.combo.addItem('Foo', 23)
    self.combo.addItem('Bar', 42)
```

A slot can be connected to the [activated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#activated) signal of the combo box, which will send the index of the item selected by the user:

```
    self.combo.activated.connect(self.handleActivated)
```

You can then use [itemText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#itemText) and [itemData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#itemData) to access the name and value via the `index` parameter:

```
    def handleActivated(self, index):
        print(self.combo.itemText(index))
        print(self.combo.itemData(index))
```

Comment: Note: if you do "itemData" pyqt returns QtVariant class, to get the value you can use self.combo.itemData(index).toString()

Comment: @Jaziel_Inc That is only needed in PyQt4, which is now obsolete and no longer supported. This question is about PyQt5.